# Integrating over the empirical distribution function (EDF)

Tags: probability-theory

Suposse I have $F$ as a CDF of a random variable $X$ and a sample $(X_i)_{i = 1}^n$ , $X_i \sim F$, iid.

$$F(x) = P(X \leq x) = E[ I(X\leq x) ]$$

I define my EDF

$$\hat{F}_n (x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} I(X_i \leq x) $$

I would like, for example, calculate $E_{\hat{F}_n}[X_i]$:

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
E_{\hat{F}_n}[X_i] & = \int xd\hat{F}_n(x)  \\
 & = \int xd  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} I(X_i \leq x)\\
 & =  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \int x \, \,d I(X_i \leq x)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Supposedly, it is known that $\int x \, \,d I(X_i \leq x) = X_i$. But I can not see the triviality of it. Some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $H(x)=I_{a \leq x}$ then $\int f(x)dH(x)=f(a)$ for any function $f$. [$H$ corresponds to the degenerate measure at $a$ and it corresponds to the constant random variable $a$].  Taking $a=X_i$ and $f(x)=x$ gives you what you want.

Comment: What is the definition of a "degenerate measure at $a$"?

Comment: Ca I say that a degenerate measure at $a$ is a measure $\mu$ such that $\mu(A) = a$ for every borelian set $A$?

Comment: No. The degenerate measure at $a$ is defined by $\mu(A)=1$ if $a \in A$ and $0$ if $a \notin A$.