Plug-in estimator of expected value

Let $g$ be the statistical functional defined by $g(\mu) = \int x \,d\mu$. Then the plug-in estimator is defined as $\hat{g}=g(L_n)$ where
$$L_n(\omega)=\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X_i(\omega)}$$ is the
empirical distribution. Here $X_i$ are independent probability
distributions. We have
$$\hat{g}=\bar{X_n}=\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$

I don't understand why the last formula is true. I think it should be pretty simple, but plugging in the definitions I get the following:
$$\hat{g}=g(L_n)=$$
$$\int \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X_i} \, d\mu = $$
$$\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n \int \delta_{X_i} \, d\mu$$
But I just don't see why we have $\int \delta_{X_i} \, d\mu = X_i$

$\int \delta_{X_i} , d\mu = X_i$ is close to being the definition of the Dirac delta function

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3265990/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1267634/321264

You're applying the definition of $g(\mu)$ incorrectly. When applied to $L_n$, you get
$$g(L_n):=\int x \,dL_n=\int x\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n d\,\delta_{X_i}=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \int x\,d\delta_{X_i}.$$ Now substitute $\int x\,d\delta_{X_i} = X_i$.
